# how to Split string to character Strings

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have a String for example: "Adam" and I would split a String into an array of single character Strings.("a","d","a","m")

your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "Adam";
String[] splitString = string.split(""); // Split string by each char
  for (String character : splitString) {
    System.out.println(character); // You can initiate object TextView here and add it to separate list
  }
```

From documentation:

> public String[] split(String regex)
>
> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.
>
> The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results
>   with these expressions:
>
> ```
> Regex     Result
> :     { "boo", "and", "foo" }
> o     { "b", "", ":and:f" }
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>       regex - the delimiting regular expression Returns:
>       the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression

Answer (score -1):

```
String str = "Adam";
TextView[] textViews = new TextView[4];
textViews[0] = textView1;
textViews[1] = textView2;
textViews[2] = textView3;
textViews[3] = textView4;
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    textViews[i] = str.charAt(i);
}
```